# How to check url exist or not in angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I want to check if a url exist or not. I'm trying using this code:

```
let request;
if ((<any>window).XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org', true);
} else if ((<any>window).ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHttp');
}

if (request) {
    console.log('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', request);

    request.open('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
    if (request.status === 200) {
        console.log('Valid Url');
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid Url');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It always return Invalid url. How can I check if the url exist or not.

Answer (score 7):

You should check this on the **server side**, as in front end side you have to deal with CORS issues

```js
function urlExists(url) {
  return fetch(url, {mode: "no-cors"})
    .then(res => true)
    .catch(err => false)
}

urlExists("http://www.mozilla.org").then(result => console.log("http://www.mozilla.org exists ? ", result ))

urlExists("http://www.mozillaaa.org").then(result => console.log("http://www.mozillaaa.org exists ?", result))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the readyState on change before reading the status.

```
var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.timeout=15000;
x.open('GET','https://example.com');
x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4){
        if(this.status==200){
            console.log('url exists');
        } else {
            console.log('url does not exist');
        }
    }
}
x.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this npm package: [url-exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-exists). Very lightweight and easy to use. Hope it helps!

Comment: But I can't import it in angular 6.

Comment: How can't you import it? Just `npm install` and import the package in the desired `.ts` file...